# BB10 - Change QML Header Title from C++

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

I'm pretty new to C++ and QML, so sort of trying to teach myself the way! I am trying to change the "title" property of a QML Header object. I am currently developing my app off the back off the pushCollector cascades example on GitHub.

I've read elsewhere that I can assign a property alias and do it that way;

```
NavigationPane {
id: navPane
property alias connectionText:connectionStatus.title
Page {
    Container {

        Header {
            id: connectionStatus
            title: "Connection Status:"
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            bottomMargin: 0.0
            topMargin: 0.0
            visible: true
            subtitle: ""            
        }
```

My question is, how do I make a void function that can dynamically change the title whenever I call the function. I need something like;

```
void App:changeConnectionText(const QString new Text)

    {
        //change object title in QML
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in .cpp

```
#include <bb/cascades/Header>
```

You access like this:

```
void ApplicationUI::changeConnectionText(QString Text) {

    Header* myheader = Application::instance()->scene()->findChild<Header*>("connectionStatus");
    myheader->setTitle(Text);
}
```

And you call it like this (in cpp):

```
changeConnectionText("Yay, connected!");
```

And QML

```
Header {
    id: connectionStatus
    objectName: "connectionStatus" //add this!!!
    title: "Connection Status:"
    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
    bottomMargin: 0.0
    topMargin: 0.0
    visible: true
    subtitle: ""
}
```

Tested, it works